# Lex: Saving entire string using starting condition and state transition

Tags: conditional-statements, state, lex

I'm wondering if it's possible to save the entire input from the start condition to the final state in lex.

For example:

```
%x START

%%

"XXX"  BEGIN START;
<START>.
<START>"YYY"  {printf("%s", yytext);}
```

Will print `YYY` if I enter something like `XXX some chars YYY`, but I'd like it to print `XXX some chars YYY`.  Is there a way to do this in lex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `yymore()` from every action in the start condition *except* the last one. `yymore()` means that there is more token to come; it causes the scanner to not reset the token
 start point.

Comment: @ rici Do you mind providing the correct syntax, or pointing me to a document with some examples?  I'm new to lex.  Is it something like `"XXX"  yymore(); BEGIN START;`?

Comment: @ rici Nevermind.  That worked.  Thanks!  That was a big help.